# Python is not executing in terminal in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

```
devroot@dev-user:~$python
```

This giving error as

```
-bash: python: command not found
```

I have tried this command to see if python is there.

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
```

The response is something as

on running `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3628976 Sep 30 13:38 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Sep 30 13:38 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 Mar  9  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1018 Oct 28  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsondiff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3661 Oct 28  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsonpatch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1342 May  1  2016 /usr/bin/python3-jsonpointer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     398 Nov 15  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsonschema
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Oct  8 12:12 /usr/bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Oct  8 12:12 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Oct  8 12:12 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Oct  8 12:12 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Jan  7 13:08 /usr/bin/python3.7 -> /usr/bin/python3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5203488 Oct 28  2019 /usr/bin/python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
```

Comment: Let's see where your shell is looking for programs. In the terminal, could you do:

echo $PATH

and post the result? That is a list of places it looks for programs to run.

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
This is what it is showing.

Comment: but when I am using python2 in terminal. Python2 shell is working. ```python2
Python 2.7.17 (default, Sep 30 2020, 13:38:04)
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: So, it's a bit odd. You have "/usr/bin" in the list, and you say you have /usr/bin/python so it should find it. Can you do "ls -l /usr/bin/python*" and post the result again. That will show us the details of all files beginning with python in there.

Comment: Another thing: You may know that the current python version is Python 3, and python 2 is out of maintenance. You really should not use python2 at all if you can. Also, some systems set "python" to be "python2" while others set it to be "python3". It's usually better to explicitly use "python2" or "python3" so you're sure you're using the version you intended to use.

Comment: As you have asked to run ```ls -l /usr/bin/python*``` I have posted below in the question.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python ` ? that file was missed in the other ls above.

Comment: I think both has same response just that below is in list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you should be using "python2" or "python3" as the command, not "python". That way you know which version you are using. And most likely what you want is "python3".

With that said, normally Ubuntu should be adding a link called just "python" that points to one of the other of the two, and I don't know why your system does not have it.

You can manually add it if you really want - but beware that this might break an update later on, and you will then need to remove the link again before you can update properly, so remember what you did here:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```

I suggest linking to python2 as this is an older 18.04 system, and "python" was python2 for that version.

If an update complains about that link being there in the future, you can delete the "/usr/bin/python" link, then run the update again.